# Create ProgressRing in delphi 2009

Tags: delphi

i'm trying to create progressring (Windows8 component) in Delphi 2009
We have lot's of samples in XAML and in C# but not in "older's" Delphi's versions.

anyway, no development company have this component to sell...

Anyone knows something about that?

Comment: Maybe http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/AdvSmoothCircularProgress.asp?

Comment: +1 to make up for the downvote

Comment: Yes, TMS have, but isn't real ProgressRing... the style is very different

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to just use an animated GIF. There are plenty of online generators available to create this GIF (for example [here](http://preloaders.net/)). You can easily inherit a custom component from `TImage` to display that GIF. Include the GIF file as a resource and load it like this:

```
ResStream := TResourceStream.Create (HInstance, 'CIRCULAR_PROGRESS', 'GIFIMG');
Img := TGIFImage.Create;
try
  Img.LoadFromStream (ResStream);
  Picture.Assign (Img);
finally
  FreeAndNil (ResStream);
  FreeAndNil (Img);
end;

if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  (Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := True;
```

Comment: What exactly do you think are the disadvantages? It works well for me.

Comment: Gif's sometimes crash in Delphi when running in Windows XP